# call function from another class swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I have one viewController that has two segment view. as the below pic shows I want to press refresh button (top left) and effect inside the segment viewColler in swift.
[image]

i couldn't add refresh button inside the segmentViewController, so is there a way to call function from fristViewController to segmentViewController by pressing refresh button ? or via prepareForSegue func ? 
P.S: viewDidLoad get some information online, by pressing refresh button this shown data will be refreshed.

I handle the segment change value like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var segment1: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch segment1.selectSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        firstView.hidden = false
        secondView.hidden = true
    case 1:
        firstView.hidden = true
        secondView.hidden = false
    default:
    break;
    }
}
```

I appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in firstViewController, there must be a function which handles a tap on the segmented control (perhaps it's called `valueChanged`). If you add a property to firstViewController:

```
var activeSegmentViewController: segmentViewController
```

and keep track of which segmentViewController is the active one in the `valueChanged` function, you can use that property to call the function:

```
activeSegmentViewController.refresh()
```

Comment: I handle segment vlaue change like as above code in firstViewController. where shuld i add var activeSegmentViewController ??